# Real Time Motion Retargeting

Tags: skeletal-animation

Using Kinect I've extracted coordinates(x,y,z) of user, I'm in search of method which can help me out transferring motion of Skeleton to any 3D model(AVATAR) using OpenNI and OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with commercial software, [it looks like this is the kind of things Natural Motion is selling with morpheme](http://www.develop-online.net/features/1344/Kinect-retargeting).